# Can Java enum class set default value

Tags: java, enums

Mycode is

```
public enum PartsOfSpeech2 {

    n("noun"),
    wp("标点"),
    a("adjective"),
    d("conjunction"),
    ...;
```

which I want

```
public enum PartsOfSpeech2 {

    n("noun"),
    wp("标点"),
    a("adjective"),
    d("conjunction"),
    %("noun");
```

can I hava a default value which is not in it， can it be set as a  default value？
because I have a type is "%", but enum is not support %, so I want a default value to solve it

Comment: The purpose of an `enum` is to have a discrete list of items from which you can select. If you want to use something which is not in the enumeration then you might want to look into using something else. Can you please provide a use case as to what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default for one who holds a reference to an `enum` without setting a value would be `null` (either automatically in case of a class field, or set by the user explicitly).

Unfortunately you cannot override the method `valueOf` for your own `enum`, as it is `static`.

But you can still create your methods:

```
public enum PartsOfSpeech2 {

    n("noun"),
    wp("标点"),
    a("adjective"),
    d("conjunction");

    private String value;

    PartsOfSpeech2(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // declare your defaults with constant values
    private final static PartsOfSpeech2 defaultValue = n;
    private final static String defaultString = "%";

    // `of` as a substitute for `valueOf` handling the default value
    public static PartsOfSpeech2 of(String value) {
        if(value.equals(defaultString)) return defaultValue;
        return PartsOfSpeech2.valueOf(value);
    }

    // `defaultOr` for handling default value for null
    public static PartsOfSpeech2 defaultOr(PartsOfSpeech2 value) {
        return value != null ? value : defaultValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return value; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [JLS 8.9. Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

> An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants. It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly instantiate an enum type (§15.9.1).

So you can't have any instance which is take default value.

You can create default constant and use that using some condition.

```
public enum PartsOfSpeech2 {
  ....
  DEFAULT("DEFAULT");
}
```

And use condition to check if your string have constant, Ex `"%"` have enum or not. if not use default value:

```
PartsOfSpeech2 result = PartsOfSpeech2.valueOf("%"); //Your String EX: %
PartsOfSpeech2 resultNew =  result==null?PartsOfSpeech2.DEFAULT: result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was the following

```
public enum YourEnum{

ENUM1("stringToMatchWith"),
ENUM2("stringToMatchWith2"),
DEFAULTENUM("Default");

public final String label;

YourEnum(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}
public static YourEnum resolveYourEnum(String stringToMatch) {
    return Arrays.stream(YourEnum.values()).filter(aEnum -> aEnum.label.equals(stringToMatch)).findFirst().orElse(YourEnum.DEFAULTENUM);
}
```

That way you can do YourEnum.resolveYourEnum("aString") and return the specified enum or the default we set